# Latex error: Unicode character ν (U+03BD)

Tags: unicode

Using overleaf, I tried to output the following sentence in a pdf form: `...$c$, then the cost of adding $v$ jobs is $vc$, here $c$ and $v$ are parameters.`

while compiling the code, there are two errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
% here pops up the 1st error: "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry"
\usepackage{setspace}  
\doublespace 
...
\subsubsection{Firms}
... 
$c$, then the cost of adding $v$ jobs is $νc$. 
% here the 2nd error: "LaTeX Error: Unicode character ν (U+03BD)".
```

The output result only shows "... *c*, then the cost of adding *v* jobs is *c*." The last formula is supposed to be *vc* rather than *c* with the parameter *v* missing.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you replace `ν` (Greek letter "nu") with `v` (Latin letter "vee")?

Comment: Oh, and the `geometry`-package options `top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm` and `margin=1in` are mutually incompatible. Which margin-related option is supposed to apply?

Comment: If you want a (Greek) nu, type in `\nu`.

Comment: It's not Greek letter nu which has been used in my paper, indeed the English letter v is what I want here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue has been solved in a comment.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. The 1st error happened at the next line ：\usepackage{setspace}@Mico

Comment: Unfortunately this issue is not solved

Comment: But the first error is the result of the line before `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` that should be removed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the line of script: \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} has been deleted, now no first error, but the 2nd error still exists@dexteritas

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestions of Mico in the comments, there are no more errors.

1. remove `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`
2. replace ν (Greek letter "nu") with v (Latin letter "vee")

If you still get errors, you should make a MWE.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\doublespace 

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Firms}
... 
$c$, then the cost of adding $v$ jobs is $vc$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it indeed works. But my problem is, in the literature, everyone use the English letter "v" to denote a specific meaning, and no one use Greek letter "nu" or Latin letter "vee", that is why I have to follow the convention using "v"

Comment: English is using the latin alphabet!

Comment: Thanks @dexteritas

Comment: With the notable exception of Greece, most European countries that were once part of the Roman Empire, or strongly influenced by Romans, actually are using the 23 latin letters plus a few additions (that unfortunately are not always shared by all the derived).

Comment: Latin letter “v” (spoken: “vee”) === English letter “v” (spoken: “vee”)